# How to check which features a particular build of SQLite supports?

Tags: ios, sqlite, compatibility

I'd like to make sure the SQLite library included with iOS 4.0 supports [foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). The official docs state:

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined.

How can I check it programmatically in C or using `sqlite3` CLI tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs say:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0
```

> Tip: If the command "PRAGMA foreign_keys" returns no data instead of a
>   single row containing "0" or "1", then the version of SQLite you are
>   using does not support foreign keys (either because it is older than
>   3.6.19 or because it was compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined).

Comment: Somehow I missed the "returns no data" part. Thanks a lot, that's just what I needed.